# Bash - How can I make selection menu of zip files based on how many zip files in a directory?

Tags: bash, files, user-interface

I am doing a theming tool script. I want to make a selection menu of zip files (zip file contain theme) in a directory, then users will choose a zip file they want to install

Example: in /theme/zipfiles/ has theme1.zip, theme2.zip, theme3.zip (users can add more theme zip file)

And I want to list those zip files in script like this:

```
Choose a theme zip file to install:
1) theme1.zip
2) theme2.zip
3) theme3.zip
# When users add more zip files and this menu will display more
```

Then I type `1` and Enter. The theme1.zip should be installing

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select`. First, set $PS3 for the prompt, and then, use `select` like a loop, breaking when you have correct data to get the desired information:

```
PS3="Choose a theme zip file to install:"
select theme_file in *.zip; do
    [[ -f "$theme_file" ]] && break
done

echo "Installing ${theme_file%.zip} from ${theme_file}..."
```

Comment: ```PS3=`echo -e "\e[1mChoose\e[21m a theme zip file to install:"` ``` if you want to emphasize "choose"

Comment: I don't see any code to show the theme file directory